# I could not connect my recyclerview in fragment with adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, fragment

my fragment class

```
class RecyclerFragment : Fragment() {
var recycler:RecyclerView? =null

private var param1: String? = null
private var param2: String? = null


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    recycler = view?.findViewById(R.id.recycler)

    }


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler, container, false)
}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    recycler?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context,RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false)


    recycler?.adapter = Custom_Adapter() // error-Unresolved reference: Custom_Adapter


}


}
```

//here is my adater

```
 class Custom_Adapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<Custom_Adapter.ViewHolder>() {


override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): Custom_Adapter.ViewHolder {
 var myViewInflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context).inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,viewGroup,false)
    return ViewHolder(myViewInflater)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Custom_Adapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return 9

}
class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your recycler fragment like this.

```
class RecyclerFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_recycler) {
var recycler:RecyclerView? =null

    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null    


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        recycler = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler)
        recycler?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context,RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false)
        recycler?.adapter = Custom_Adapter()
    }


}
```

And you have to move classes `Recucler_Item` and `Custom_Adapter` into correct java package.

Comment: thank you but it still not working.. may I show you my repository on GitHub to check the problem?  https://github.com/Mussa-Adolai/MyRecycler

Answer (score 1):

From your repo link in one of the comments, `Custom_Adapter` is under your `src/test` directory. It needs to be under `src/main` where `RecyclerFragment` can see it - that's why you're getting `unresolved reference` errors. Stick it in there with everything else

`main` and `test` are different [source sets](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html#sec:java_source_sets), it's basically a way of keeping stuff separate. All your production code goes in `main`, and it can't see anything in `test` by default. When you run tests, those use everything in `test` (and maybe `androidTest`) and get all the stuff in `main` included, since the tests need access to the production code to, y'know, test it!